# What stops a user from reading a million times from the firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Since loading data from the firstore happens on the client side what stopps a user from writing a script that just reads the same collection a million times or a trillion times? You could use security rules, but if that user should have access to that data, for example items in a webshop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users have the ability to query a collection directly from the client app, there is nothing stopping them from reading all documents in that collection that the security rules allow.

If you need to place some limits on how much a user can read, you will have to implement some sort of backend API that tracks how much the user has queried, and rejects further calls after the limit is exceeded.